# How to use the neighborhood modifier of grass:r.mapcalculator in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, raster-calculator, qgis-processing

I would like use r.mapcalculator in a PyQGIS processing script to change values from one raster in another accordingly. I don't know how to call the variables row and col, which are now read as simple strings in the following code:

```
processing.runalg('grass:r.mapcalculator',{"amap": rlayer, "bmap": emptylayer, 
"formula": "amap[row,col]=bmap[(%i+row*%i),(%i+col*%i)]"% (offset,scale,offset,scale), 
"GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER": "%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), "outfile": bdry_resamp})
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax to use this?

It would be fine to do it manually calling the module from the processing toolbox in QGIS as well, but then I would have to specify the 'formula' as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completness also here:
I am not familiar with the peculiarities of Processing in PyQGGIS. However, a map-calculator command like:

```
r.mapcalc expression="amap=bmap[1,1]"
```

would make “amap” a copy of “bmap” where pixel values are shifted one pixel to the left and one up.

Thus, you processing formula might look like this (not tested...):

```
"amap=bmap[(%i+%i),(%i+%i)]"% (offset,scale,offset,scale)
```

See also:
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.mapcalc.html#the-neighborhood-modifier

Edit: OK, obviously I did not read your question carefully enough.
Use `r.mapcalc` (and not r.mapcalculator), upated code above.

Comment: I only did some initial test to run your suggestion in a script and manually with the formula `'amap=bmap[30,30]'`. The former doesn't give any error (and no result), the later a 'Parse error' for the formula in the log file. I guess I only did something small wrong and it could work as you suggest. However, I now solved it by reading both raster with `gdal.Open()`, reading the data as a array with `band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)`, iterating over all rows and columns, writing the modified values to a new array and writing that to a new raster with `gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create()`.